# sending data over js and receive pdf from action controller

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm sending two strings from my view to the controller using javascript. Controller receive that strings and based on their values return pdf page. I'm using [this approach](http://www.semanticarchitecture.net/www/pdf-reporting-using-asp-net-mvc/) for creating pdf on the fly. Everything is fine, I'm getting pdf when I look inside firebug, but I don't know what to do inside javascript success operation, how to display this pdf on the view.

my js is

```
function GetDetails2(xx, xxx) {
$.ajax({
         url: ('/PdfReport/MyreportDemo'),
         type: 'POST',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         data: JSON.stringify({ dataOne: xx, dataTwo: xxx }),
         success: function (result) {                 
                    //alert("ok");
                },    
         error: function () {
               alert("error");
        }
       });
 }
```

Comment: can you be clear: is your intent to *show* the PDF as part of an existing page? perhaps consider loading it into an iframe instead of using ajax here?

Comment: I just realize that I do not need ajax call at all, please post Iframe solution as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript isn't very good at handling binary data. The only way to directly handle this is by encoding the data as a [base-64 encoded data-uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). Posting JSON trough an `<iframe>` won't work either, since you need a `<form>`.

A possible solution would be to change the back-end to accept uri-parameters:

```
/PdfReport/MyreportDemo?dataOne=xx&dataTwo=xx
```

Then you could use an `<iframe>`:

```html
<iframe name="hiddenframe" style="display: none;" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<form id="reportDemoForm" method="post" action="/PdfReport/MyreportDemo" target="hiddenframe">
  <input id="dataOne" name="dataOne" type="hidden" value=""/>
  <input id="dataTwo" name="dataTwo" type="hidden" value=""/>
</form>
```

```js
$('#dataOne').val('xx');
$('#dataTwo').val('xx');
$('#reportDemoForm').submit();
```

This assumes you want to download the file. If you want do display it on the page, you can instead show the `<iframe>`, and size it appropriately.

Comment: minor point: since the introduction of typed arrays, javascript can handle binary data *just fine*; that is unrelated to the main question, though